# Destroy gameobject in unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, project, monodevelop, unityscript, gameobject

In unity3d i declared

```
var ribbon : GameObject;
```

In start function i have used code

```
Destroy (ribbon.gameObject, 5);
```

which shows error "Destroying assets is not permitted to avoid data loss.
If you really want to remove an asset use DestroyImmediate (theObject, true);"

how can i destroy this gameobject?

Thanks in advance

Comment: hmm... have you tried `DestroyImmediate`?

Comment: @ Jan Dvorak: In game code it is recommended to use Object.Destroy instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Destroy(gameObject.Find("ribbon"), 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could Just do `Destroy(ribbon,5);` if you have assigned the ribbon gameobject already 
ribbon is already a gameobject no need to do ribbon.gameObject

Comment: Hey Tungamirai Mangombe, even though your answer seems to be quite right, it isn't generally a good practice to answer something that has already been answered by someone else. In this case it is also already accepted two years ago.